# Azure pipeline Cache@2 task fails for go package cache

Tags: go, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I was creating a cache to minimize the build time of a go test command. I created a cache on path /go/pkg/mod to save downloaded packages.
I first tried a basic setup like the following

```
- task: Cache@2
    inputs:
      key: go-package-cache
      path: /go/pkg/mod
- script: go test ./...
```

Then I tried the following after investigating the examples for yarn package caches on the documentation.

```
- task: Cache@2
    inputs:
      key: '"go" | "$(Agent.OS)" | go.mod'
      path: /go/pkg/mod
      restoreKeys: 
        go | "$(Agent.OS)"
        go
- script: go test ./...
```

In both cases, the pre-job for the cache prints a `cache miss` warning and then the post-job for the cache fails with the error

```
There is a cache miss.
tar: /go/pkg/mod: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

I expected that there would be a cache miss on the first run and then it would create a cache on the post-job. But it seems there is something I am missing. And if it matters, the job is running on a container.

Comment: It worked without any modification. I have no idea what the problem was and I couldn't even reproduce it again. I literally reverted to commits that failed before but it still passes now. This error has been bugging me for more than a day and It just disappeared without any trace!